# How to change a static boolean variable in a button action listener?

Tags: java, actionlistener, static-variables

```
public class Main
{
  private static boolean SaH=false,LaE=false;

  public static void main(String[] args{
    //other code
    choice1.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                        
                     SaH = true;
                     frame.dispose();
                }
            }
        );

   if (SaH==true)
   {
      // more code
```

When I run the program, the frame goes away via the `dispose()` method; but it won't enter the if-statement (`SaH` isn't changing).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Java. The statement if (SaH==true) is executed when the java program loads as it is within main method. If you want to execute it after the dispose() method, then create a new method and call the method straight after dispose() within the actionListener